# Leaf.xNet.HttpException: "Could not receive the message body of the response HTTP-server 'example.com'"

Tags: c#, http, request, httprequest, xnet

This error appears only on this link, other links work correctly

***Internal exceptions (1/2)*** - IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection. An attempt to establish a connection was unsuccessful because the required response was not received from another computer within the required time, or an already established connection was terminated due to an incorrect response from an already connected computer.

***Internal exceptions (2/2)*** - SocketException: An attempt to establish a connection was unsuccessful because the required response was not received from another computer within the required time, or an already established connection was terminated due to an incorrect response from an already connected computer.

I tried to add different headers, cookies, or make a default "clean" request.

Moreover, the **postman** correctly receives the body, as well as **HttpClient**.

I will be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some sites it is not possible to make requests with this framework. Solved the problem by rewriting the code on HttpClient.